# How to delete many files with the same name?

Tags: node.js, file

Looking to get some help.
I want to delete files that have the file name "**person**",in Codeigniter I can use the code as below :

```
$this->load->helper('directory');
$map =  directory_map('./_cache/', FALSE, TRUE);
$cb = array();
foreach($map as $file){
    if (strpos($file, $_post['fname']) !== false) {
        unlink($file);
        $cb[$file] = "deleted";

    }
}
return $cb;
```

the results of a successful trial only delete a single file, code as below :

```
this.remove = function (fname, callback) {
    const filesname = secret.pathCache + fname;
    fs.unlink(filesname, (err) => {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        callback("Removed : " + filesname);
    });
}
```

[image]

maybe someone can help me, to provide information on how to delete many files with the same name, with only one execution, thank you.

fullcode :

```
var fs = require('fs');
const secret = require("../Secret");

function Cache() {

    this.add = function (fname, contents) {
        const filesname = secret.pathCache + fname;
        const resjson = JSON.stringify(contents);
        fs.writeFile(filesname, resjson, 'utf8', function (err) {
            if (err)
                throw err;
        });
    }

    this.view = function (fname, callback) {
        const filesname = secret.pathCache + fname;
        let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(filesname);
        let data = JSON.parse(rawdata);
        return callback(data);
    }

    this.check = function (fname, callback) {
        const filesname = secret.pathCache + fname;
        fs.exists(filesname, function (exists) {
            if (exists) {
                res = "cached";
            } else {
                res = "null";
            }
            return callback(res);
        });
    }

    this.remove = function (fname, callback) {
        const filesname = secret.pathCache + fname;
        fs.unlink(filesname, (err) => {
            if (err)
                throw err;
            callback("Removed : " + filesname);
        });
    }

    this.removeAll = function (fname, callback) {
        fs.readdir(folder, (err, files) => {
            files.forEach(file => {
                callback("Removed : " + file);
            });
        })
    }
}

module.exports = new Cache();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use readdir to get the files in the directory then filter out the matching files and delete them.

```
this.remove = function (fname, callback) {
    fs.readdir(secret.pathCache, (err, files) => {
        files = files.filter(file => file.includes(fname));
        let len = files.length;
        for(const file of files){
            fs.unlink(secret.pathCache + fname, err => {
                if(--len <= 0){
                    callback();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Promise.all` to track progress of file deletion. First read the directory and filter out file path(s) based on `fname`

```
this.remove = function (fname, callback) {
  fs.readdir(secret.pathCache, (err, files) => {
    files = files.filter(file => file.includes(fname));
    // you may need to construct path "f" here.
    const unlinkPromises = files.map(f => fs.unlink(f))
    Promise.all(unlinkPromises).then(callback);
  });
}
```